Paillier's paper, can't find subgroup of order φ(n)
Paillier's paper (
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-48910-X_16.pdf), page 3 Definition 1:
Definition 1. A number $z$ is said to be a n-th residue modulo $n^2$ if there exists a number $y∈Z^∗_{n^2}$ such that
$z=y^n$  mod $n^2$.
The set of n-th residues is a multiplicative subgroup of $Z^∗_{n^2}$ of order φ(n).
So let $n=3*2=6$, $φ(6)=2$, for all $x \in Z^*_{n^2}$ the following table shows $x^i$ mod $36$. Since for all $x$, $x^6$=1, "The set of n-th residues" contains only a single element 1. But this set is supposed to contain $φ(6)=2$ elements and should be a subgroup. Any idea why?



$x^1$
5
23
11
29
17
35
7
25
13
31
1
19




$x^2$
25
25
13
13
1
1
13
13
25
25
1
1


$x^3$
17
35
35
17
17
35
19
1
1
19
1
19


$x^4$
13
13
25
25
1
1
25
25
13
13
1
1


$x^5$
29
11
23
5
17
35
31
13
25
7
1
19


$x^6$
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1




The question shows that the quoted proposition does not apply to $n=6$. That's because $n$ is even, which is excluded by the paper (emphasis mine):

We set $n=p\,q$ where $p$ and $q$ are large primes

Further, the paper implicitly assumes that, as customary in RSA, $p$ and $q$ are chosen secretly in a way such that the factorization of $n$ is hard, implying that $p\ne q$. The later is also apparent when the paper states $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$.

Proof that the set $\mathcal S_n$ of $n^\text{th}$ residues is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_{n^2}^*$. All there is to prove is that if $z_0,z_1\in\mathcal S_n$, then $z=z_0\,z_1^{-1}\bmod n^2\in\mathcal S_n$. By definition, there exists $y_0,y_1\in\mathbb Z_{n^2}^*$ with $z_0=y_0^n\bmod n^2$ and $z_1=y_1^n\bmod n^2$. Define $y=y_0\,y_1^{-1}\bmod n^2$. We have $y,z\in\mathbb Z_{n^2}^*$ because $\mathbb Z_{n^2}^*$ is a group under multiplication modulo $n^2$. And by repeated use of associativity of that internal law, we get $z=y^n\bmod n^2$, thus $z\in\mathcal S_n$, QED.

Proof that $|\mathcal S_n|=\phi(n)$ if $n$ is the product of distinct odd primes: uh…

Example with $n=15=3\times 5$. It holds
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb Z_{n^2}^*=\{&1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14,16,17,19,22,23,26,28,29,31,32,34,37,38,41,43,\\
&44,46,47,49,52,53,56,58,59,61,62,64,67,68,71,73,74,76,77,79,82,\\
&83,86,88,89,91,92,94,97,98,101,103,104,106,107,109,112,113,116,\\
&118,119,121,122,124,127,128,131,133,134,136,137,139,142,143,\\
&146,148,149,151,152,154,157,158,161,163,164,166,167,169,172,\\
&173,176,178,179,181,182,184,187,188,191,193,194,196,197,199,\\
&202,203,206,208,209,211,212,214,217,218,221,223,224\}\end{align}$$
The set of $n^\text{th}$ residues is $\{1,26,82,107,118,143,199,224\}$, which indeed has order $\phi(n)=\phi(15)=\phi(3\times5)=2\times4=8$.

Note: I used $\phi(n)$ as in the paper where the question has $\varphi(n)$. These are equivalent.

Quote from the paper :"Definition 1. A number z is said to be a n-th residue modulo $n^2$ if there exists a number $y ∈ Z^_{n^2}$ such that $z = y^n$ mod $n^2$.
The set of n-th residues is a multiplicative subgroup of $Z^{n^2}$ of order φ(n)."  It is not the set of residues mod $n$ ie $Z^_n$ as you said. And according to the paper, it should be SUBGROUP of $Z^{n^2}$.

@Jason: you are right! So I return to my original explanation, which is that $n$ is even.

@fgrieu, thanks for your proof that $S_n$ is a subgroup.  So why isn't its order $\phi(n)$ when $n$ is even?

Notice that I changed my proof that $\mathcal S_n$ is a subgroup, since it's not sufficient to prove that it's closed under the group law. I'm making repeated mistakes on this Q!! And since I'm stuck at proving $|\mathcal S_n|=\phi(n)$, I can't pinpoint where in this proof we need $n$ odd. But I have an analogy in $\mathbb R$: if $n$ is odd, $y^n$ reaches the whole of $\mathbb R$, but when $n$ is even it only reaches $\mathbb R^+$.

That analogy makes sense. Thanks.
